# Infinite loop error with .htaccess when I add 301 redirect with WordPress in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have my WordPress website in a subdirectory. I used the WordPress codex directions to set this up and all worked well until client asked me to add a 301 redirect to solve an issue with some links to an old domain on the Internet. The old domain name points to the new website but does not use a permanent 301 redirect. The current domain name is Encoreco.com.

The old domain points to the same place but it is not a 301 redirect (you can see that the URL does not change at the top and for some reason this means that my javascript slideshow doesn't work). Here is what happens: [encoreconstructionco.com](http://encoreconstructionco.com/)

When I add a 301 redirect to solve this problem, I get the infinite loop errors. Here is the line of code that attempts to solve the issue with the old domain but creates the infinite loop:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://encoreco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And here is my current .htaccess: Note - I tried taking the .html rewrite and the www rewrite out and that did not solve the problem.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://encoreco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

… will redirect everything, including correct requests, so you have to get an infinite redirect.

Restrict that rule to wrong host names only:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !encoreco\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://encoreco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```